# Smash Up: Microbot Fixer + Microbot Alpha

Tags: smash-up

The [Microbot Fixer](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/05/SU_Robot_MicroFixer.jpg) has the ability:

> If this is the first minion you played this turn, you may play an extra minion. **Ongoing: Each of your Microbots gains +1 power.**

If the Microbot Fixer is already in play, can I play the [Microbot Alpha](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/05/SU_Robot_MicroAlpha.jpg) with its ability:

> **Ongoing** : Gains +1 power for each of your other Microbots. **All of your minions are considered Microbots.**

to **boost the power of my other non-robot/non-Microbot** cards in play?

Put another way, does the phrase "All of your minions are considered Microbots" affect my other cards (by modifying them into Microbots, allowing them to benefit from the +1 fixer ability), or does it only serve to guide the calculation of the Microbot Alpha's final power?

Answer (score 4):

**All your minions gain +1 power, because they are all Microbots.**

From the [FAQ](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/08/SU-FAQ.pdf),

> Q: When a card makes all of your minions microbots, and further then gives all of your microbots strength bonuses, is the effect only local to the base those cards are located or are those effects global?
>
> A: If the text does not reference “on this base” or “at this base” then it is global.

Additionally, the [rules explain](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/06/AEG-SU-Rulebook.pdf) how to handle **Ongoing** abilities. Since both the **Alpha Microbot** and **Microbot Fixer**'s effect are active as long as it is in play, all your Minions are Microbots and they all gain +1 Power, and the Alpha gets an additional bonus equal to the number of other Minions.

> **Ongoing**: Most abilities happen, and then they're over. Ongoing abilities are active for as long as they're in play.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree.

The card reads "Gains +1 power for each of your other Microbots. All of your minions are considered Microbots."

The wording on the Alpha says that all minions are *considered* microbots in direct response to the prior sentence, if you were wondering how to calculate that number. It has one power, not two. The second sentence does indeed clarify the first. It does not transform all your zombies into microbots, thus making the microbot fixer a buff to every minion of yours.

While I understand the argument, in these situations I try to go by the spirit of the game. A card transforming everything into microbots would not have used the word "considered." It would say "all your minions are now microbots."

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back this up? The other answer cites the faq,